# Why am I receiving 410 Gone error in pytube?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

While running some basic code for pytube to get and print the url of a YouTube video I am getting 410 gone error.

This is the code I have:

```
 from pytube import YouTube
 
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" #Hard coded Rick Roll
video = YouTube(url)
 
print("*****Video Title*****")
print(video.title)
```

And this is the output I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/will/Documents/Coding test/import pytube.py", line 4, in <module>
video = YouTube(url)
File "/Users/will/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pytube/__main__.py", line 91, in __init__
self.prefetch()
File "/Users/will/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pytube/__main__.py", line 181, in prefetch
self.vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
File "/Users/will/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pytube/request.py", line 36, in get
return _execute_request(url).read().decode("utf-8")
File "/Users/will/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pytube/request.py", line 24, in _execute_request
return urlopen(request)  # nosec
File "/Users/will/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/Users/will/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "/Users/will/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 632, in http_response
response = self.parent.error(
File "/Users/will/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 555, in error
result = self._call_chain(*args)
File "/Users/will/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/Users/will/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 747, in http_error_302
return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
File "/Users/will/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "/Users/will/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 632, in http_response
response = self.parent.error(
File "/Users/will/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 561, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/Users/will/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/Users/will/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone
```

I have tried running an update to pytube but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pytube
```

Comment: Can you access the URL in a browser (i.e. you get a 200, with the page loading the video)? If so, do you have anything enabled in the browser that changes your location (e.g. using a proxy server, maybe certain request headers, ...)?

Comment: If you can access the video in a browser, there's something different about how the two requests are being made. I asked the above as I don't know whether YouTube returns a 410 when a video is no longer accessible in certain locations.

Comment: @Willguy24. Wait at least 3 fays.